# Atlas gives wrong information

Tags: atlas

Tor Atlas informs me "No results found. No Tor relays or bridges matched your query" But when I use find my ip location tool I am shown to be exiting in another country.  I worry that I am exiting through a fake exit node.

Answer (score 1):

[Atlas](http://atlas.torproject.org/) had some problem in the last days. It seems that the backend onionoo was not working properly. This also affected [Globe](https://globe.torproject.org/). It works properly now. So you should check if still you get the message from Atlas.

Another possibility to check if an IP address was a Tor relay is [Exonerator](https://exonerator.torproject.org/). Just enter the address and a date and it will tell you if it was an exit during this time.